# display user front end submitted post on google map

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I already have front end posting system. I have one custom post type called "requirement". It is a real estate site. In that requirement form, user submit his name,mail,address and requirements description. I want to show this requirements submitted by all users on google map in one page.i am searching over google  but I didn't get any plugin that fits my need. So anybody knows about this??

Comment: I think you should add custom code for google map

Comment: I m using wpestate wordpress theme.do u have any idea about that??

Comment: then, may this theme will have code for multiple properties on google map. You can use that by replacing the post type as "requirement".

Comment: thnks...I m going to try that..